# How can I serve a static website offline written in React without NPM?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router

I'm trying to distribute a website/web app written with React. In the past, I was able to just distribute the build folder and run index.html but after adding react router, it seems that I have to serve it with some server. Since the people I'm making it for doesn't want it to be hosted on the server like Serve, they will have to serve it themselves.

I've tried [Static Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server) but that requires installing NPM. Is there a way to bundle static server in the build folder so that the `static serve` command can be run without NPM or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're not limited to Node and can use any static server you wish. Node isn't the best way to serve static files in production environment. As for Node, see `pkg`.

Comment: No matter what server you use you will have to setup service workers if you want to make it work offline. To serving the static site you can use express js or the native node http module.

Comment: I've tried pkg with the command `pkg -c package.json src/index.js` but it gives me an unexpected token error pointing at React.render.